# Skype notifications not turning off

Tags: 14.04, skype

I installed Skype in Ubuntu 14.04, and attempted to turn off the annoying online/offline notifications by unchecking "Enable Event" for "Skype Login" and "Skype Logout" in the Notifications menu of Options. I still get the notifications for both, however. How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow the steps below:

1. Sign in to Skype application.
2. Click on the Skype icon (menu) located at the lower left corner of the application window.
3. Select Options...
4. Click on Notifications tab.
5. In the list, select Contact Came Online.
6. Untick the Enable Event and Play Sound File (below).
7. Select Contact Went Offline.
8. Untick the Enable Event and Play Sound File (below).
9. Click Apply button.

[View solution in the original post:](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux-archive/Cannot-disable-sound-notifications/m-p/2121595#M3754)

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the steps below:
Sign in to Skype application.
Click on the Skype icon (menu) located at the lower left corner of the application window.
Select Options...
Click on Notifications tab.
In the list, select Contact Came Online.
Untick the Enable Event and Play Sound File (below).
Select Contact Went Offline.
Untick the Enable Event and Play Sound File (below).
Click Apply button.